# GeoServer keeps redirecting to /geoserver/

Tags: geoserver, apache, jetty

I have geoserver installed on Debian. On top of that I run apache that proxies requests to jetty.

```
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
```

So far so good, redirects are working properly. The domain on the server is `geodata.mydomain.com` and I dont want to add `geoserver` to the URL. This works for a part with the `ProxyPass /` and settings the `Proxy Base URL` in Geoserver. But when I go to `geodata.mydomain.com`, Geoserver keeps redirecting to `geodata.mydomain.com/geoserver/web`. How can I prevent this behaviour? I just want an error page on this page, since it isn't a valid request. I already disabled the user interface on Geoserver and tried to rewrite the URL in apache with the code below, but without succeeding.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^geoserver/ 
RewriteRule (.*) /$1
```

Also about the error page. Now I get that ugly default Jetty 404 page with `HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found` and some information. Can I change this default page? I just want to show `Invalid request` message or something.

Comment: Did you configure the proxy base URL inside geoserver? https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html if not.

Comment: Yes, is configured. That part is also working correctly, but the problem is the default redirection on the domain and the error 404 page layout.

Comment: The 404 is off topic here

Answer (score 1):

there is the solution that I found

```
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPass /geoserver/ http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver/ http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
```

(I just added the two lines in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when proxied through httpd, request headers do not "arrive" at GeoServer.
By adding a directive in httpd.conf should do the trick.
Here is an example:

## Map GeoServer on httpd folder

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass        "/geoserver" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
ProxyPassReverse "/geoserver" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
```

Comment: This is incorrect, as told in my answer, the requests do arrive at GeoServer.